# Can You Remotely Install Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Is it possible to remotely install visual studio team foundation 2012?

If anyone can link to a tutorial or information guide that would be great if there is one available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May need clarification on exactly what you want.

1) It's possible to install TFS2012 remotely using remote desktop

2)  You can script an install using unattended installs, and probably start the install remotely using powershell or something similar

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfsao/archive/2012/10/01/unattended-installation-of-tfs-2012.aspx
http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/